# list missing numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

Let m=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; be a set and let  s=[ 2,4,5,6,8,9]; be a subset of m. How do list all missing numbers in s from m.

For example, the missing numbers in s from 1-->10 are 1,3,7,10. So, how can list them?

Thanks.

Comment: You want `Complement`

Comment: I felt like a downvote at first, but `Complement` doesn't seem to come up quickly when searching the documentation with keywords from the OP. Still, the documentation deserves a more thoughtful read, `Complement` is quite a trivial function that comes up early on, learning the language.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, have a look at,

[Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ListsOverview.html)

[Constructing Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstructingLists.html)

[List Manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

[How to | Use Brackets and Braces Correctly](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseBracketsAndBracesCorrectly.html)

[The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)

and

[Complement](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html)

> Find which elements in the first list are not in any of the subsequent
>   lists

```
m = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

s = {2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9}

Complement[m, s]
```

> ```
> {*
> {1, 3, 7, 10}
> *}
> ```